# Django REST Framework: how to make the index route browsable if routes are prefixed?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've no use for the index route `api.domain.tld/`. Instead my routes start quite nested:

- `api.domain.tld/v1/some/thing/`
- `api.domain.tld/v1/foo/bar/`

When I visit `api.domain.tld/` I get a `404` - which makes sense, but I'd like to get browsable suggestions of the nested routes instead.

**Relevant code:**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'some', ThingViewSet)
router.register(r'foo', BarViewSet)

urlpatterns = 
    # path('', '...') - is not in use
    path('v1/', include(router.urls))
]
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: @Shayne I can't remember, but stopped using DRF.